# php user login from database won't login

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi i've made a login script, but it won't log me in, and keeps telling me incorrect match. Here's my code:

```
include_once("dbConnect.php");

// Set the posted data from the form into local variables
$usname = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$paswd = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

$usname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $usname);
$paswd = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $paswd);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$usname' AND usertype = '1' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$uid = $row[0];
$dbUsname = $row['username'];
$dbPassword = $row['password'];

// Check if the username and the password they entered was correct
if ($usname == $dbUsname && $paswd == $dbPassword) {
    // Set session 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $usname;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $uid;
    // Now direct to users feed
    header("Location: user.php");
} else {
    echo "<h2>Oops that username or password combination was incorrect.
    <br /> Please try again.</h2>";
}
```

The username is admin, and passcode is PPsleep1 and the usertype is 1, you can try yourself: http://daltyapps.com/daltyapps/portfolio/paypal/log/index.php

Comment: It looks like you are storing **passwords in clear text** thats a VERY BAD Practice.

Comment: your **username** is unique ????

Comment: Just add a `var_dump($row);` before you try to do the IF test. See what is actually in the database fields.

Comment: I would suggest not to store passwords without any hashing in the database. Manual database queries may be good for practising, for production systems I'd recommend to use either a framework or at least some libraries. Thumbs up that you do username and password comparison in two steps, please do not do both in one query as suggested below. To debug your application, use var_dump for both the user-entered values and for the database values and compare those.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It says NULL, but i can see that the fields in the table is filled

Comment: @waza-ari It's just for testing right now.

Comment: @DanielJuhlSørensen: Maybe post your database layout then.

Comment: Then either the database connection has failed or the query has failed. Add some code to test that all these completed successfully

Comment: Stop using a deprecated API (`mysql_*`) and start using PDO. Start using prepared statements and bound params. Hash your passwords using `password_hash()`. Also never use weak comparison https://3v4l.org/sU17P unless you have a very good reason to do so.

Answer (score -1):

With the current situation, I can suggest you following fixes in the code:

```
<?php 
include_once("dbConnect.php");

// Set the posted data from the form into local variables
$usname = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$paswd = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

$usname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $usname);
$paswd = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $paswd);

// use both username and password to retrieve records from table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$usname' AND password = '$paswd' AND usertype = '1'";

$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
if($query) // check if query runs properly or is having any error
{
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1) // check if ony one user with 'USERNAME - PASSWORD' pair exists in database
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $uid = $row[0];
        $dbUsname = $row[INDEX_OF_USERNAME_FIELD];

        // Set session 
        $_SESSION['username'] = $usname;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $uid;
        // Now direct to users feed
        header("Location: user.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h2>Oops that username or password combination was incorrect.
        <br /> Please try again.</h2>";
    }       
}
else
{
    echo "Error in query ".mysqli_error($dbCon);
}
?>
```

Comment: Why did you add the password to the query.

Comment: Page gone fully blank then.

Comment: what is the reason not using password in select query and fetching data from database with only username and then comparing passwords?

Comment: @DanielJuhlSørensen have you changed `$row[INDEX_OF_USERNAME_FIELD];` to a desired index? Also try turning on errors on your page to get full idea of whats going wrong and where?

Answer (score -1):

Use below code,

```
include_once("dbConnect.php");

// Set the posted data from the form into local variables
$usname = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$paswd = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

$usname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $usname);
$paswd = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $paswd);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$usname' AND usertype = '1' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query); /*comment - have replace row with array*/
$uid = $row[0];
$dbUsname = $row['username'];
$dbPassword = $row['password'];

// Check if the username and the password they entered was correct
if ($usname == $dbUsname && $paswd == $dbPassword) {
    // Set session 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $usname;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $uid;
    // Now direct to users feed
    header("Location: user.php");
} else {
    echo "<h2>Oops that username or password combination was incorrect.
    <br /> Please try again.</h2>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Second option to use,

```
include_once("dbConnect.php");

// Set the posted data from the form into local variables
$usname = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$paswd = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

$usname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $usname);
$paswd = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $paswd);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$usname' AND usertype = '1' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query); 
$uid = $row[0];
$dbUsname = $row[1]; /*comment - if column username after column id in table */
$dbPassword = $row[2]; /*comment - if column password after column username in table*/

// Check if the username and the password they entered was correct
if ($usname == $dbUsname && $paswd == $dbPassword) {
    // Set session 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $usname;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $uid;
    // Now direct to users feed
    header("Location: user.php");
} else {
    echo "<h2>Oops that username or password combination was incorrect.
    <br /> Please try again.</h2>";
}
```